# Timeouts with async await in Node.js not working?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

```
app.get('/testAsync', asyncHandler(async function (req, res,next) {
  //res.send('We test async here')

  async function display(name) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log("displaying "+name)

      returnBody += name + " ";
      return 1
    }, name + "000");
  }


  async function send()
  {
    console.log("sending "+returnBody)
    res.send(returnBody)
    //returnBody="";
    console.log('all done!')
    return 'alldone';
  }

  const getInfo = async () => {
// failed attemp 1
    // display("1")
    // display("2")
    // display("3")
    // display("4")
    // display("5")

//failed attempt 2
    // display(1).then(
    //   display(2)).then(
    //     display(3)).then(
    //       send()
    //     )
    

//failed attempt 3
    // await display(1)
    // await display(2);
    // await display(3);
    send(await display(1),await display(2),await display(3));
    //await send(display1,display2,display3)


  }

   await getInfo();



}))
```

Ideally, I'd like my console to read:

- displaying 1
- displaying 2
- displaying 3
- sending
- all done!

Instead the console is displaying

- sending
- all done!
- displaying 1
- displaying 2
- displaying 3

What am I doing wrong? Not sure if it matters or helps but the idea behind the timeouts is to imitate sql executions.

Comment: you need to resolve the promise returned by `display` function after the timeout has finished. Change `display` function from an `async` to a regular function that returns a new promise which is resolved after specific number of seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the `display` function so that it resolves the promise only after the function scheduled with `setTimeout` is executed, for example:

```
function display(name) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log("displaying "+name)
      returnBody += name + " ";
      resolve(1);
    }, name + "000");
  })
}
```

Comment: @horusoftheblackflame You are welcome! I would appreciate if you accept and upvote the answer if you find it helpful.